# Тег strong и ранжирование

Tags: html, seo, поисковые-системы

В мире SEO есть мнение, что ключевые слова, если их оборачивать в теги `strong`, `em` `ins`, будут учитываться лучше поисковиками. Поэтому в далёкие нулевые (стандарты поисковиков меняются стремительно) очень часто приходилось наблюдать на некоторых сайтах наворот ключевых фраз, выделенных жирным шрифтом, делающих текст нечитабельным для человека.

Известно ли вам о том, что оборачивание ключевых слов в данные теги как-то влияет на ранжирование?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выделение ключевых фраз жирным | курсивом определенно влияет на ранжирование. Влияние как положительное, так и отрицательное может быть. Все зависит от "аппетита" выделяющего. Есть такое понятие, как "переспам". Он может относиться как к ключевым словам, так и к форматированию текста. Если каждую вторую ключевую фразу будете выделять жирным, то однозначно словите фильтр.

- Выделять ключевые слова стоит только, если это уместно.
- Выделять можно не только КС, но и окружающий текст, если это помогает направить внимание посетителя на данный участок текста.
- Не нужно думать, что если КС в тексте не выделено жирным, то в поиске вы будете последним по этому КС.
- Влияние не большое при отсутствии выделения и огромное при переспаме.

И т.д.